# Amazon web services with EC2 weblogic over https

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, weblogic

I purchased a domain on AWS and used the load balancer wih acm certificate to securely route to my web application deployed on my EC2 instance using tomcat server. 
**This routing is working and is accessed over https:// with certificate issued by AWS**

The application on tomcat server uses webservices deployed on the same EC2 on a weblogic server running on port 7001. The weblogic server however uses the http protocol right now.

**PROBLEM**

I can not get content from the web services as its not secure. I was trying to think about possible solutions:

1. Am i required to enable SSL on weblogic with a keystore and certificate?
2. Will it work even thought the certificate given by AWS is different from the certificate generated by weblogic?
3. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Thanks,

Anil

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have more data in order to help you, but here it goes. It sounds like the error you're getting is (insecure) mixed content (Tomcat via HTTPS, Weblogic via HTTP). If that's the case,

1. Yes.
2. Yes, it should.
3. It depends. Do you need to have Tomcat and Weblogic co-located? Is Weblogic only accessible from the Tomcat instance? If so, your solution seems the best to me (self-generate the Weblogic certificate). If your Weblogic is accessible from outside Tomcat, you can also deploy it behind a load balancer, on a different EC2 instance, and generate a different ACM certificate. But that is sounding overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I got it figured out yest. I ended up deploying the services application in tomcat as well. Now the load balancer is using https to connect to both the services and the website.